# Google Cloud not allowing access to Jupyter Notebook

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, jupyter-notebook, ip-address

I am extremely new to Google Cloud, however earlier this week I used some youtube tutorials to set up an instance on google cloud and how to set up jupyter notebook through the SSH. Access worked fine for two days however suddenly today I am getting an error when I want to access the notebook.

The VM starts fine, then I write this code in the shell:

```
jupyter-notebook --no-browser --port=2000
```

to which the shell shows the correct output:

```
[I 08:28:39.959 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/vella_rebecca7
[I 08:28:39.959 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 08:28:39.959 NotebookApp] http://dissertation:2000/
[I 08:28:39.959 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
```

after this I usually open a new tab in Chrome write my external IP and port (externalip:port) and I get access to my notebook. However, I am now getting an error and I am not allowed to access the notebook.

The error: `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`.

I have set my IP address to static and even tried to set up a completely new instance, however I am still getting the same issue. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

(I saw a lot of posts on the internet saying my domain is pointing to the wrong IP address, but I don't know what this means because I have never set up any domain, all I did was start an instance on google cloud)

Answer (score 0):

Let me address two points in my answer.

- First of all, the suggested way to use Notebooks in GCP is [AI Platform Notebooks](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/introduction)
  You only need to create an instance, [default](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/create-new#create_an_instance_with_default_properties) or [custom](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/create-new#create-with-options), via de console UI or the [command line](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/create-new#create-command-line). Afterwards, you can access JupyterLab simply clicking [Open JupyterLab on the console UI](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/create-new#open_the_notebook_2) or use SSH to establish a connection and then visit http://localhost:8080 to access JupyterLab (details [here](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/ssh-access)).
- Secondly, regarding your issue, I would suggest some of the solutions provided in this [chrome support page](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/6144098?hl=en&msgid=13374613). More precisely, changing DNS server to Google DNS or OpenDNS , or removing all cookies and cached files on your browser should help to resolve this issue. Moreover, you have this [serverfault issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/968659/error-dns-probe-finished-nxdomain-google-cloud-platform-wordpress-site-custo) where the same error is described. You can follow the same checks that are done there.